# JUnit - one test for different implementations

Tags: java, junit

I have got a little problem with writing tests for my program. I have an SortingAlgorithm interface, and a few implementations like BubbleSort, InsertionSort, QuickSort...

I don't want to make a TestCase for each of these SortingAlgorithms implementations. I want to inject each of this algorithms class into one TestCase, and then run TestCase for each algorithm separately.

How to do that?

My code:

```
public class SortingAlorithmTest {

SortingAlgorithm sortingAlgorithm;
final int amount = 50000;
final int delayTime = 0;
int[] numbers;

public SortingAlorithmTest(SortingAlgorithm sortingAlgorithm){
    this.sortingAlgorithm = sortingAlgorithm;
}

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    Random random = new Random();
    numbers = new int[amount];

    for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++){
        numbers[i] = random.nextInt(Preferences.numberScope);
    }

    AlgorithmDelayer.setDelayTime(delayTime);
}

@Test(expected = NullPointerException.class)
public void passingNullValueTest(){
    sortingAlgorithm.sort(null);
}

@Test(timeout = 1000)
public void sortingSpeedTimeTest() {
    sortingAlgorithm.sort(numbers);
}

@Test
public void correctSortingTest(){
    sortingAlgorithm.sort(numbers);

    for (int i = 0; i < amount - 1; i++){
        assertTrue(numbers[i] <= numbers[i+1]);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: http://www.mkyong.com/unittest/junit-4-tutorial-6-parameterized-test/

Comment: Thats it! ;) Thank You!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a [Parameterized](http://www.mkyong.com/unittest/junit-4-tutorial-6-parameterized-test/) test:

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
class MyTestClass {
  private final SortingAlgorithm algo;

  public MyTestClass(SortingAlgorithm algo) {
    this.algo = algo;
  }

  @Parameters 
  public static List<Object[]> getParameters() {
    List<Object[]> params = new ArrayList<>();
    // Build your list of parameters somehow.
    params.add(new Object[] { new BubbleSort() });
    params.add(new Object[] { new QuickSort() });
    // ...
    return params;
  }

  @Test
  public void test() {
    // Exercise your algorithm somehow.
  }
}
```